# Knockout Template Binding ViewModel data as argument

Tags: knockout.js

I am reposting this as my older post was not very clear.

I have a KO View Model liek this with a complex object like this (with lists and child lists, etc.) - much simplified than what I actually have:

```
$(function () {

function MyViewModel() {
  this.collection = {
    List: [{ name: 'amar', progress: 20 },
           { name: 'vijay', progress: 50}]
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

Then at some point I am passing an object (that is deep inside the KO View Model) to a function like this where I want to create a div for that item:

```
var createDivs = function (item) {
// "task-template" is defined in my html
var itemDiv = $("<div  data-bind=\"template: { name: 'task-template', HOW_DO_I_REFERENCE_item_HERE?  }\" ></div>");
itemDiv.appendTo("#ParentDiv");
}
```

But, as you can see in the above code, I am not sure how to refer the item object (or specify that as the data source) while defining the itemDiv template? Can someone help?

The requuirement is that I want to bind the style of this div to some property in the item (that's in the KO view model).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the $parent, $parents, and $root objects http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

Comment: Actually, what I am trying to do is that instead of specifying the list source ("collection.List" in the code below) declaratively in my template like this:

var itemDiv = $("<div  data-bind=\"template: { name: 'task-template', colection.List  }\" ></div>");

I want to know how to specify a list (that's already in the KO view model, deep within a hierarchy) in code manually.

Thanks